# Undefined index in Array

Tags: actionscript-3, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have my grid-array in my flash game that has a set sized index in it, and through some code it sometimes checks outside of the Array index. Is there a way I can check to see if a index slot is undefined/existent

Gives me a TypeError #1010

```
public function fnPopulate(X:int, Y:int, Grid:Array){
    if (Grid[ X + 1 ][ Y + 1 ] != null || Grid[ X + 1 ][ Y + 1 ] != undefined ) {
    return(true);
    } 

    return(false);
}
```

Any advise is appreciated, Thank you in advance.

P.S. Is there a reason why it keeps deleting my greeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check the first dimensional of array.
and `obj!= null, obj!= undefined`  means `if(obj){....}`

```
public function fnPopulate(X:int, Y:int, Grid:Array)
{
    if (Grid[ X + 1 ] && Grid[ X + 1 ][ Y + 1 ]) 
    {
        return(true);
    } 

    return(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if ( (X<Grid.length) && (Y<Grid[X].length) ) return(true) else return(false);
```

Comment: If true is returned it then attempts to places a object in that Index slot. So I kind of need to check if it is there or not.

Comment: Tried adding your suggestion in this way at the start of the function: if (X+1 >= 10 || +1 >= 9) {return(true);} Still errors later on in the code because sometimes I still will address non-existing index.

Comment: you could simplify this even more: return (X<Grid.length) && (Y<Grid[X].length);